# edit form validation error

Tags: php, codeigniter

when i am performing validation on edit form it gives an error: 
undefined variable score_id on line no-16, and then for all variable that is student_name, subject_name, marks.

my controller file.

```
public function edit($id)
{ 
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $score_id = $this->uri->segment('3');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('std_name','student_name','trim|required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_name','subject_name','trim|required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('marks','marks','required|numeric');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {   
            $score_id = $this->uri->segment('3');
             $this->load->view('edit_score');

        }
        elseif($this->input->post('edit') && $this->input->post('edit_id')!='')
        {       

        $score_id = $this->uri->segment('3');
        $data = array(

        'score_id' => $this->input->post('score_id'),  
        'student_name' => $this->input->post('std_name'),
        'subject_name' => $this->input->post('txt_name'),
        'marks' => $this->input->post('marks'),

        );
        $result = $this->score->update_record($id,$data);
        header('location:'.base_url().'index.php/score_listing');       

    } 

    if($id)
    {
        echo "this is score_id".$id;
    $result = $this->score->edit_score($id);
    $data['action'] = 'edit';
    $data['score_id'] = $result[0]->score_id;
    $data['student_name'] = $result[0]->student_name;
    $data['subject_name'] = $result[0]->subject_name;
    $data['marks'] = $result[0]->marks;
    }
    echo "welome to edit page";
    $this->load->view('edit_score',$data);  
}
```

this is my edit file

```
<h1>Edit score</h1>
<?php $action = $score_id!='' ? 'edit/'.$score_id : 'add'; ?>
<form name="edit_score" method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="score_id" value="<?php echo $score_id;?>"/>
<?php echo form_hidden('admin_id',$this->load->session->userdata('admin_id')); ?> 
    <!--for above function use form helper in controller file -->

    <table style="width:100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>student Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="std_name" value="<?php echo $student_name; ?>"/></td>
        <?php echo form_error("std_name"); ?>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>subject Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txt_name" value="<?php echo $subject_name; ?>"/></td>
        <?php echo form_error("txt_name"); ?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>max marks:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="marks" value="<?php echo $marks; ?>" /></td>
        <?php echo form_error("marks"); ?>
    </tr>

        <tr>    
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="edit" value="Submit"/></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
```

my uri is: http://localhost/ci/index.php/score_listing/edit/1

it gives following error:
Edit score

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: score_id
>
> Filename: views/edit_score.php
>
> Line Number: 16
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\views\edit_score.php
>   Line: 16
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\controllers\score_listing.php
>   Line: 64
>   Function: view
>
> File: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci\index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

Comment: **line no-16** of which page??? Post your full error message along with your url!!

Comment: your if condition not working so your score_id variable not define

Comment: post code of this method $this->score->edit_score($id);

Answer (score 1):

At first time load or when validation false it will run this code

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {   
        $score_id = $this->uri->segment('3');
         $this->load->view('edit_score');

    }
```

Here array argument not passed to view file like this  $this->load->view('edit_score',$data);. So you have declare the null value or some other what you before the validation and should pass the array argument value

```
$data = array(
    'score_id' => '',  
    'student_name' => '',
    'subject_name' => '',
    'marks' => '',
    );

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {   
        $score_id = $this->uri->segment('3');
         $this->load->view('edit_score',$data);// here is changes pass $data

    }
```

Comment: Thanks gopal sir for your help. I prefer your ans with few changes and also change in if condition. obviously your suggestion not enough for answer but help me a lot.